# How to test locally in a browser using import and export

Tags: javascript

According to [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file), browsers have had support for loading ECMAScript modules directly.

So why does this not work on my local computer

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script type="module">
        import { hello } from './hello.js'; // Or the extension could be just `.js`
        hello('world');
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

hello.js

```
export function hello(text) {
    alert(text);
}
```

The console keeps giving me CORS error

> Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/JavascriptImportExport/hello.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: Opening local files directly (through `file://` URIs) has many restrictions in place, so that malicious programs can't access your data. To make it work, you have to access your site through a local server (google "localhost server" for more on how to set up one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load modules from `file://` protocol URLs.

You need a web server for this. If you're working with VS Code and just need a webserver to test and learn, I recommend you install the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension.

The error message already tells you this:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: 
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Comment: if they are using visual studio, the play button will create a website on a random port.